# how return data since a GET request with node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I have a little trouble with an Node application, the problem is: I have an Script in a web site "x" and this script calls a function that is on another server (like analytics), I'm calling the function with ajax and when the function returns the data, happen some curious, when I check the network with Developer Tools in Chrome, the callback shows the response like I wanted in JSON format, but not show me data. My code:

```
var xml2js  = require('xml2js'),
    http    = require('http'),
    request = require('request');

var parserController = function (aw){

    console.log('Parse Controller load');

    aw.get('/ads/:keyword/:sid/:pid/:count', function (req,res){
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request('http://'+req.params.sid+'.'+req.params.pid+'.autoweb-xml.com/feed?&sid='+req.params.sid+'&auth=2Al5&subid=&q='+req.params.keyword+'&ip=127.0.0.1&ua=Mozilla/5.0%20(Windows%20NT%206.1;%20WOW64;%20rv:26.0)%20Gecko/20100101%20Firefox/26.0&ref=awebads.lan&count='+req.params.count+'&state=&city=', function (error, response, body) {
     if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var parser = xml2js.parseString;
        var data = '';

            parser(body,{explicitRoot : false}, function (err, result){
        if(!err){
            data = result;
            dataP=data.results[0];
            dataS=dataP.sponsored[0];
            console.log(dataS.listing);
                return res.send(dataS.listing);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
            })

          }
        })//en del request
    });
};
```

and my call function is:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
          url:'http://HOST/ads/'+configParams.keyword+'/'+configParams.envSource+'/'+configParams.envPublisher+'/'+configParams.envCount,
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    async: false,
    crossDomain : true
})

xhr.done(function (data){
    console.log(data);
    data.forEach(function(item){
    window.collections.ads.add(item);
});
}).fail(function (err) {
    //console.log('failed');
    //console.log(err)
});
```

when I display the data in the console, this part show me the XMLHTTPRequest, thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Are there any Error messages? Could it be an Same-Origin-Policy issue? or is the first code the server and the second one on an other server?

Answer (score 1):

You are sending JSON:

> the callback shows the response like I wanted in JSON format

… but the client is expecting JSON-P

> ```
> dataType : 'jsonp',
> ```

Either:

1. Tell the client to expect JSON (or just remove the `dataType` line and let it use the Content-Type header) and set [`Access-Control-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) on the response headers to give the site permission to access it cross-domain *or*
2. Send JSON-P back instead (look at `callback` in the query string, send `Content-Type: application/javascript` (not JSON!), and return `callback_value(your_json);` as the response body.

Answer (score 0):

In case of jsonp you need a callback function and then return your response in that callback.